# How to add to Array and Update 'max' Value in one statement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Example

```
//Entry 1 (value 7)

{
stuff : "goods"
values : [7],
max : 7,
}

//Entry 2 (value : 3)

{
stuff : "goods"
values : [7, 3],
max : 7,
}

//Entry 3 (value : 9)

{
stuff : "goods"
values : [7, 3, 9],
max : 9,
}
```

Things I've tried

```
db.people.aggregate(
  {$match:{stuff:"goods"}},
  {$unwind:"$values"},
  {$max:1}
   //lost ? {$set : {max : 1}} ??
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method merely "queries" data, and does not actually "modifiy" documents permanently in the database. So you still want [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) to actually make changes, and you read the incorrect documentation for [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/max/), which is a "different" operator that is actually applied in "updates":

So for each iteration:

```
db.people.drop();
db.people.update(
  { "stuff": "goods" },
  { 
    "$push": { "values": 7 },
    "$max": { "max": 7 }
  },
  { "upsert": true }
);

// { "stuff": "goods", "values": [7], "max": 7 }


db.people.update(
  { "stuff": "goods" },
  { 
    "$push": { "values": 3 },
    "$max": { "max": 3 }
  },
  { "upsert": true }
);

// { "stuff": "goods", "values": [7,3], "max": 7 }

db.people.update(
  { "stuff": "goods" },
  { 
    "$push": { "values": 9 },
    "$max": { "max": 9 }
  },
  { "upsert": true }
);

// { "stuff": "goods", "values": [7,3,9], "max": 9 }
```

So "that" version of [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/max/) only makes the modification in the document "when" the value supplied is "greater than" the present value of the existing property. Of course [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/min/) does the opposite.

Whilst both of those share the same named as operators used in "aggregation pipelines", they in fact have a completely different function. And in this case, that is the function you are looking for.